# How to bring a specific category product to the first position in prestashop1.6.1.3

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

How to bring a specific  category product to the first positionin the home page where product is displayed in prestashop 1.6.1.3,I have  category called big and car ,
But even I arrange the category position the product of the Big ticket Category is not appearing to the first position in the home page product listing page .
How to bring my Big ticket category to the first position

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The products listed on any page in PrestaShop is fetched from the database by adding certain filters and shown on the listing through a loop.

In case you want to sort their order then you need to edit the getProducts() function in Category.php class file.

This is a quite complex task, so you have to be careful.